# Magento what is due amount, when it is generated or is it admin setting?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, invoice

I have been working with Magento 1.9.x version for quite a long time.

But yet I have no idea when is the Total Due amount generated, is it generated after the Invoice is Paid ?

Please anyone provide full information on "Total Due" amount which is displayed in Order and why not displayed in Invoice and how to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the total due amount an invoice for that order.

And this quite fair to do it manually. Because when you will use a COD payment method at that time how system will know that what amount has been paid?

That's why i will say that this is good to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Order placed if it not paid, total due amount is equal to grand total. It's calculate when order placed.

E.g I have two item in order but one is invoiced means it paid and other one is remain as unpaid.See in below image.

[image]

Total due does not on invoice because While invoice any order it will capture amount.